# JS Node Recursion arrange Directories

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, directory

I am new to Javascript and I use Node.js.

Imagine we have a directory with a lot of directories in it. I want to give the content of each of them out, no matter how deep in the directory.

The thing is I want to give them out in the right order, so you can interpret which file was in which folder.

I've got actually no idea how to do it, I think I have to use a recursion but I am pretty bad at those things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is a good entry point for you:**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var walkPath = './';

var walk = function (dir, done) {
    fs.readdir(dir, function (error, list) {
        if (error) {
            return done(error);
        }

        var i = 0;
        (function next() {
            var file = list[i++];

            if (!file) {
                return done(null);
            }

            file = dir + '/' + file;
            fs.stat(file, function (error, stat) {
                if (error) {
                    return done(error);
                }

                if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) {
                    walk(file, function (error) {
                        next();
                    });
                } else {
                    // do stuff to file here
                    console.log(file);

                    next();
                }
            });
        })();
    });
};
```

**Reference:**  [Loop through all files in a given directory with node.js](https://gist.github.com/adamwdraper/4212319)

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: Thanks helped me a lot